# jrepl.bat only prints the first line

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make [jrepl.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) work on several lines. See this little test:

```
set NLM=^


set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%
echo First line%NL%second line | jrepl.bat i o
```

Is there a reason why it only prints the first line:

```
Forst lone
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MCND mentioned it's a problem of the child process and that the line is parsed two times.

But it can be done with a simple linefeed.

```
set LF=^


cmd /q /v /c"echo First line^!LF^!second line" | jrepl.bat i o
```

This works independent of the delayed expansion mode.

As if delayed expansion is enabled in the batch file, the exclamation marks are escaped in the delayed expansion parser phase (and the carets are removed).
Else with delayed expansion disabled the line with the carets will be executed unchanged in the child cmd.exe process, but there the carets are removed in the special charaters phase so the delayed expansion will also work later.

Answer (score 0):

Pipes are created between processes, so, the `echo` command is executed in a separate `cmd` instance that does not parse the input line (with the inner line feeds) as you expect.

Try with

```
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set NLM=^


set NL=^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%
cmd /q /v /c"echo First line!NL!second line" | jrepl.bat i o
```

Comment: Too much, now you get three lines `First line`, `<empty>` and `second line`